# Reshape row into column of the 2d array in a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, reshape

Consider the following matrix:

```
M <- cbind(c("ID001", "ID003", "ID002", "ID002", "ID003"),
           c("BK101", "BK145", "BK101", "BK125", "BK101"), 
           c(6, 3, 2, 7, 3))
```

I want to reshape the matrix, so I get the following matrix:

```
       BK101 BK125 BK145
ID001    6     0     0
ID002    2     7     0
ID003    3     0     3
```

I have tried with:

```
reshape(M, idvar=[,1], timevar=[,2])
```

But that does not work.

Comment: Any particular reason why it's a matrix and not a dataframe ? Seems like reshaping  long to wide problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format

Answer (score 2):

If you name your columns and put them in a data frame:

```
M <- data.frame("a"=c("ID001","ID003","ID002","ID002","ID003"),
                "b"=c("BK101","BK145","BK101","BK125","BK101"),
                "c"=c(6,3,2,7,3))
xtabs(c~a+b,data=M)

       b
a       BK101 BK125 BK145
  ID001     6     0     0
  ID002     2     7     0
  ID003     3     0     3
```

Comment: Or `as.data.frame(unclass(xtabs(as.numeric(as.character(V3)) ~ V1 + V2, data=as.data.frame(M))))` (Note: OP's `M`).

Comment: Thanks. That is perfect, jay.sf :-)

Answer (score 2):

The general pattern when creating a matrix:

First create an empty matrix where you will store your results.

```
X <- matrix(0, nrow=length(unique(M[,1])), ncol=length(unique(M[,2])),
            dimnames=list(sort(unique(M[,1])), sort(unique(M[,2]))))


X
      BK101 BK125 BK145
ID001     0     0     0
ID002     0     0     0
ID003     0     0     0
```

Then add the data.

```
X[M[,1:2]] <- as.numeric(M[,3])

X
      BK101 BK125 BK145
ID001     6     0     0
ID002     2     7     0
ID003     3     0     3
```

Comment: Most likely this is because your `M` is a `data.frame` and not a `matrix`, as indicated by the answer. Try changing the last line to `x[as.matrix(M[,1:2])] <- as.numeric(M[,3])`

Answer (score 1):

Another option with `dcast`

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(M, a~b, fill = 0)
#      a BK101 BK125 BK145
#1 ID001     6     0     0
#2 ID002     2     7     0
#3 ID003     3     0     3
```

---

Or with `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
 M %>%
     pivot_wider(names_from = b, values_from = c, values_fill = list(c = 0))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  a     BK101 BK145 BK125
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 ID001     6     0     0
#2 ID003     3     3     0
#3 ID002     2     0     7
```

#### data

```
M <- data.frame("a"=c("ID001","ID003","ID002","ID002","ID003"),
                "b"=c("BK101","BK145","BK101","BK125","BK101"),
                "c"=c(6,3,2,7,3))
```